# GAE and Flask: DuplicatePropertyError is raised when importing a Model inside a __init__ file

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I am creating a Flask based Web application with GAE Python 2.7 Standard Environment. When I try to import Animal Model inside application/__init__py file and other files, App Engine SDK raises DuplicatePropertyError.

```sh
DuplicatePropertyError: Class AnimalKind already has property animal_set
```

```sh
.
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── src
│   ├── app.yaml
│   ├── application
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── animal_bp
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── views.py
│   │   ├── appengine_config.py
│   │   ├── main.py
│   │   ├── models
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── base_models.py
│   │   │   ├── common_models.py
│   │   │   └── kind_models.py
│   │   └── settings.py
│   ├── index.yaml
│   ├── lib
```

## app.yaml

```
service: default
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
instance_class: F1

builtins:
- appstats: on
- remote_api: on

libraries:
- name: ssl
  version: latest

inbound_services:
- warmup

# [START handlers]
handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: .*
  script: run.application.app
  # script: main.app
  secure: always
# [END handlers]
```

## run.py

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(1, os.path.join(os.path.abspath('.'), 'lib'))
sys.path.insert(1, os.path.join(os.path.abspath('.'), 'application'))

import application
```

## application/**init**.py

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os

from flask import Flask, g, request, session
from werkzeug.debug import DebuggedApplication
from animal_bp.views import animal_bp
from models.common_models import Animal


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object('application.settings.Local')
    app.wsgi_app = DebuggedApplication(app.wsgi_app, evalex=True)
    app.register_blueprint(animal_bp)
    return app

app = create_app()
```

## application/models/common_models.py

```py
from google.appengine.ext import db
from models.kind_models import AnimalKind


class Animal(db.Model):
    """
    Animal Model
    """
    animal_kind_name = db.ReferenceProperty(AnimalKind)
```

## application/models/kind_models.py

```py
from google.appengine.ext import db


class AnimalKind(db.Model):
    """
    Kind Model
    """
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
```

## application/animal_bp/views.py

```py
from flask import Blueprint
from models.common_models import Animal

animal_bp = Blueprint('animal_bp', __name__)


@animal_bp.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello world1'
```

For example, if I delete "from models.common_models import Animal" in animal_bp/views.py. the error is not raised. Of course when I remove "from models.common_models import Animal" from application/**init**.py file, the error is not raised.

I don't have any duplicate property but maybe initialization process run twice due to my directory structure. Sorry for such a long question, but any help will be welcomed!!

Answer (score 0):

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
from models.kind_models import AnimalKind


class Animal(db.Model):
    """
    Animal Model
    """
    animal_kind_name = db.ReferenceProperty(AnimalKind)
```

The error seems to be that you are creating a ReferenceProperty without giving it an explicit name.

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
from models.kind_models import AnimalKind


class Animal(db.Model):
    """
    Animal Model
    """
    animal_kind_name = db.ReferenceProperty(AnimalKind, name='testName')
```

I think this was not necessary in some old versions but after (1.7.6+) they have changed the way of initializing instances.

And FYI Python 2 support on Google Cloud already ended on January 1, 2020, and all developers are encouraged to upgrade to Python 3 as soon as they can.

[Python2 Sunset](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/python2-sunset/)

Comment: I set the collection_name but it still raises the same error.

Comment: Did you also try to just change the property name to something else and see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

DuplicatePropertyError [happens If you have multiple ReferenceProperty values that refer to the same model class](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/datamodeling#References). A solution for this is to explicitly set the collection_name argument in ReferenceProperty, like in:

```
class Animal(db.Model):

    name = db.ReferenceProperty(AnimalKind, collection_name='test_reference')
```